# "Missing ServletContext" in CometD configuration (version 3.1.2) using Spring Boot Web Application (version 1.5.4)

Tags: java, spring-boot, cometd

Everything works fine when using the primer described in the [CometD Reference Book](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_primer). The versions of Spring, CometD and Jetty harmonizing together.

Now, I (a spring boot newbie) want to setup a Spring Boot Web Application (version 1.5.4) with CometD (version 3.1.2). And I also want to do the configuration via annotations without web.xml as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25845197/2331957).

For that I found the github project "Livechat" which provides an "*Example how to prepare the WebsocketConfiguration*" for CometD in a Spring Boot project - I wasn't able to get it running.

All my attempts failed to get a simple spring boot application running with an annotated CometD configuration.

**So, I ask for help, to setup a Spring Boot Application:**

- based on version 1.5.4
- CometD (version 3.1.2)
- Working on both: jetty 9.x and tomcat (if possible)
- Using annotations instead of web.xml

---

Here is the main exception I got during my tests: **Missing ServletContext**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing ServletContext
at org.cometd.websocket.server.WebSocketTransport.init(WebSocketTransport.java:60) ~[cometd-java-websocket-javax-server-3.1.2.jar:na]
at org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl.initializeServerTransports(BayeuxServerImpl.java:255) ~[cometd-java-server-3.1.2.jar:na]
at org.cometd.server.BayeuxServerImpl.doStart(BayeuxServerImpl.java:135) ~[cometd-java-server-3.1.2.jar:na]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.4.6.v20170531.jar:9.4.6.v20170531]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
... 29 common frames omitted
```

**WebApplication.java**:

```
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WebApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }
}
```

**CometDConfiguration.java** (as described in the "*CometD Reference Book*" chapter "*9.3.3.26. Annotation Based Spring Configuration*":

```
@Component
public class CometDConfiguration implements DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor, ServletContextAware {
    private BayeuxServer bayeuxServer;
    private ServerAnnotationProcessor processor;

    @Inject
    private void setBayeuxServer(BayeuxServer bayeuxServer) {
        this.bayeuxServer = bayeuxServer;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        this.processor = new ServerAnnotationProcessor(bayeuxServer);
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
        processor.processDependencies(bean);
        processor.processConfigurations(bean);
        processor.processCallbacks(bean);
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean requiresDestruction(Object bean) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeforeDestruction(Object bean, String name) throws BeansException {
        processor.deprocessCallbacks(bean);
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public BayeuxServer bayeuxServer() {
        BayeuxServerImpl bean = new BayeuxServerImpl();
//        bean.setOption(BayeuxServerImpl.LOG_LEVEL, "3");
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        servletContext.setAttribute(BayeuxServer.ATTRIBUTE, bayeuxServer);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <cometd-version>3.1.2</cometd-version>
        <jetty-version>9.4.6.v20170531</jetty-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP and JSTL SUPPORT -->
        <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Cometd dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>bayeux-api</artifactId>
            <version>${cometd-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.javascript</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-javascript-jquery</artifactId>
            <version>${cometd-version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-java-server</artifactId>
            <version>${cometd-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-java-websocket-javax-server</artifactId>
            <version>${cometd-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-java-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${cometd-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-java-oort</artifactId>
            <version>${cometd-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util-ajax</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>apache-jstl</artifactId>
          <version>${jetty-version}</version>
          <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
          <version>${jetty-version}</version>
          <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/cometd-primer</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Was able to reproduce, looks like an initialization ordering problem. I'm looking into this, stay tuned.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34525337/how-to-create-a-bean-after-servletcontext-initialized-in-spring-boot

Comment: Spring boot starts the embedded Servlet container _after_ resolving the dependency injections of the beans, and therefore the `ServletContext` is not yet available.  This is different from normal Spring (and the CometD documentation you refer to) because you typically start the Servlet container and therefore the `ServletContext` _before_ Spring.  I don't know if there is a way to tell Spring Boot to resolve the beans _after_ the embedded Servlet container is started.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into it. The link above didn't get an answer since 1.5 years.

Comment: Shall I stop trying to run a Spring Boot application? Do you see any chance to get it running?

And, how could it be possible that the livechat project - I mentioned in the question - was able to run a spring boot application with an older version of spring, cometd and jetty?

Comment: I'll be meeting a bunch of Spring Boot experts the next week, will let you know what they say. By looking at Spring Boot source code, it's evident that they did start the container _after_ dependency injection resolution. This means that you can at least start CometD in Spring Boot without configuring BayeuxServer in code (but in `web.xml`).

Comment: Is there any news on this topic?